# Cross-service calls with Akka

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor, akka.net

I'm playing with newly released Akka.Net 1.0 (congratulations on the release!) so it's all quite new to me, but I'm pretty sure anyone with JVM Akka experience could also chime in since there's nothing that's runtime-dependent in the question.

Let's consider several (for the sake of example, 2) separate services that are a part of a larger system/application. Those services usually do their own things, but cross-service calls are sometimes needed. Let's say that `Service 2` can be standalone and has a `GetStuff` action. `Service 1` has a `DoSomething` action, which has to get the result of `GetStuff` action first.

What is preferred way of handling that kind of situation when both services can be deployed separately and to different machines?

As I said, I don't know much about Akka, but digging through examples, docs and source I found two options:

1. Remoting. Separate actor systems in their own services using `Remoting` to get `ActorSelection` from remote host. It would be pretty much the same as [Remoting docs example](http://getakka.net/docs/Remoting), just that two actor systems would be equal 'clients'.
2. Clustering. I'm trying to wrap my head around that and the most I can figure out right now would be to set up a separate cluster service that would just set up the cluster system, creating a simple listener actor so that the seed node could be properly initialized (?). Then each and every separate actor system created in their own services would join to said cluster system under different role.

Maybe there's yet another solution that I'm not aware of...?

Personally, clustering solution seems harder to grasp and set up at first glance, but maybe there are some significant advantages that I can't see right now.

To reiterate, what is the preferred way of handling such situation and what should I look out for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka.Cluster depends on Akka.Remote - here's what's fundamentally different about them:

- **Akka.Remote** - allows you to connect and communicate with actor systems running in remote processes. Can be totally separate code-bases running entirely different Akka.NET applications ("services", if you will.) All you need to communicate between the two systems is a shared set of message classes that's visible in both processes.
- **Akka.Cluster** - an abstraction on top of Akka.Remote that eliminates the need for each of your service instances to have to know the explicit address of every other possible service instance you might need to connect to. These can be instances of the same services or instances of different services. Enables dynamic discovery of services via a really simple "seed node" strategy.

I recommend you take a look at the [Akka.Cluster microservices example](https://github.com/petabridge/akkadotnet-code-samples/tree/master/Cluster.WebCrawler) that I wrote - it shows how you can use the Akka.Cluster "roles" feature to dynamically make cross-service calls to nodes in a different service without having to explicitly define any of their network addresses. In particular, take a look at how I use "cluster-aware" routers to do this.

Comment: Thanks! That's almost perfect, really close to what I want, although it is a bit complicated. Anyway, seems to be working just fine, even if my own sample app loosely based on it doesn't :) I guess I got configuration wrong somewhere, I'll have to figure it all out, there's a lot that I don't grok here just yet. From all that I gather that Clustering should be the default way to approach that issue, thanks!

Comment: Quick and small question, I tried to narrow down my issue with 'not working' and I have a pretty small and self-contained example where a call to actor selection from another process doesn't do anything (but works from the same process) - where would be the best place to link the repo so I could ask how to configure the cluster? I tried to adapt the configuration from example you gave, but it's a bit 'too much' for now... :)